# DLL versions and Visual Studio attach to process

Tags: visual-studio, dll, reporting-services

I'm trying to use VS's attach to process tool to debug add-ins I'm developing for Sql Server Reporting Services.

I am able to correctly debug it with attach to process when I copy dll's and pdb's in my project debug/bin dir to the ReportServer/bin dir.  But, if I use my msbuild script and copy those dlls and pdbs to the ReportServer/bin dir I get the wrong version.

1) **How do I check the current version of a dll/tell if a dll is incompatible with another version?**

2) **And how do I tell what dll's/versions are loaded by the ReportServer process?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Sql Server Reporting Services, but

1) you can inspect the version of a DLL with ildasm.exe

2) when you use VS 'attach to process', in the 'Modules' window it shows the version numbers of all the loaded assemblies